# Using a listing inside a figure-like environment

Tags: tables, captions, listings, grammar

I am writing a document dealing with formal grammars, containing numerous examples. I decided to use the `lstlisting` environment from the `listings` package over the mathematics `align` and give example grammars in the following manner

```
\begin{lstlisting}
S -> A | B
A -> aA | empty
B -> b
\end{lstlisting}
```

It might be useful to refer to the grammar examples given at various points throughout the documents, so I would like to give it a caption and `\ref` to it as if it were a figure.

Putting the listing into the figure, however, fails (the listing will disappear and the caption will not appear at all).

Is there any captioned environment in latex, perhaps similar to `figure` or `table` that can be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `listings` package already has a built in mechanism for captions and labels using the eponymous keys as shown in the following example. By default, such a listing will not float, as oppsoed to `figure` or `table`, so this approach might be useful, if you are just interested in adding caption and label. If you also want your listing to float, you can add the `float` key as in `\begin{lstlisting}[caption={caption text here}, label={mylabel}, float]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Grammar Example}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={caption text here}, label={mylabel}]
S -> A | B
A -> aA | empty
B -> b
\end{lstlisting}

Reference to the example: \ref{mylabel}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{Grammar example}{tbph}{loe}

\begin{document}
    \begin{Grammar example}
        \begin{lstlisting}
        S -> A | B
        A -> aA | empty
        B -> b
        \end{lstlisting}
        \caption{A formal grammar}
        \label{mylabel}
    \end{Grammar example}

\ref{mylabel} is an excellent example of a formal grammar.
\listof{Grammar example}{List of example grammars}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are the packages `capt-of` and `float` needed here?

Comment: Nope, but I didn't know that at the time of posting this answer. I only came to know about it after @leandriis's answer :) I myself recommend their answer now!

Comment: Not sure though if the `\listof{<float>}{<name of list>}` is provided by any `lstlistings` internal macro.

Comment: Okay. `\listof` is from `float` package. I did not notice that. `capt-of` package seems to be redundant (according to manual of capt-of).